# dojox.layout.TableContainer using div instead of table element

Tags: dojo

I'm creating a table container programmatically as described [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/layout/TableContainer.html).

But I see that it is not using a table element as described in the documentation. Instead it is using a div. So the children flow if the parent is resized. The labels don't show up either. This is how it ends up looking.

[image]

Here is my code. detailPane in the code is dijit/layout/ContentPane and it's parent is dijit/layout/BorderContainer. What am I doing wrong?

```
    var programmatic = new TableContainer(
            {
              cols: 2,
              showLabels: true
            });
    detailPane.addChild(programmatic);
    var text1 = new TextBox({label: "ProgText 1"});
    var text2 = new TextBox({label: "ProgText 2"});
    var text3 = new TextBox({label: "ProgText 3"});
    var text4 = new TextBox({label: "ProgText 4"});

    // Add the four text boxes to the TableContainer
    programmatic.addChild(text1);
    programmatic.addChild(text2);
    programmatic.addChild(text3);
    programmatic.addChild(text4);
    programmatic.startup();
```

Thanks,

Comment: have you called `startup()` (i.e `detailPane.startup()` ) on the contentpane at the end of adding chid widget?

Comment: I'm not calling startup() on `detailPane` but I do call `startup` on `programatic` after adding the last child text4.

Comment: you need to show your entire code for us to understand where you are making a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/yu3ery3b/) over here with TableContainer layout inside a ContentPane.

The JS part:

```
require(["dojo/parser","dijit/layout/ContentPane","dojox/layout/TableContainer", "dijit/form/TextBox","dojo/domReady!"], function (parser, ContentPane, TableContainer, TextBox ) {

var myCP = new ContentPane({
        style:"height:125px"
    }, "putWidgetHere");    

// Add the custom class "labelsAndValues"
var programmatic = new TableContainer(
{
  cols: 2,
  customClass:"labelsAndValues",
  "labelWidth": "150"
} /*,"putWidgetHere" */);

// Create four text boxes
var text1 = new TextBox({label: "ProgText 1"});
var text2 = new TextBox({label: "ProgText 2"});
var text3 = new TextBox({label: "ProgText 3"});
var text4 = new TextBox({label: "ProgText 4"});

// Add the four text boxes to the TableContainer
programmatic.addChild(text1);
programmatic.addChild(text2);
programmatic.addChild(text3);
programmatic.addChild(text4);

    myCP.addChild(programmatic);
    myCP.startup();

});
```

The CSS part:

```
.labelsAndValues-labelCell {

  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.labelsAndValues-valueCell {

  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I observed from your fiddle that you were adding `programmatic` to `myCP` after adding the text boxes to `programmatic`. I did the same. That is moved `detailPane.addChild(programmatic);` to the end and it worked. I'm still left wondering how that makes a difference.

Comment: I am not an expert, but from my understanding the contentpane needs to know the size of it widgets before displaying and placing them correctly. So when you call startup at the end it calculates the correct size for all the widgets and loads them properly.

Comment: I had the same issue and noticed that I was declaring the Dojo TableContainer in the HTML part but the ComboBox content was just an <input> element that I populate in the JS code part. For some reason I couldn't fathom why the labels were not appearing for my ComboBoxes but now I know that, in my case, I just handle everything in JS part (with the startup) so that all controls happen in sync!